# Need help making a 3d keychain pendant

Tags: mesh, objects

I have been fighting with this for the past week and am pretty much about ready to throw it away. I am trying to make keychains for a party and have had nothing but issues and I am almost out of time to get them done. I tried to upload the 2d image and it wouldn't upload properly so I had to do each detail individually and combine them. (I have already given up on making the text look clean.) In the process of combining each object together, my object is now done but has NO solid faces that I can extrude to make it into a 3d object nor can I add a hole for a ring (where there is currently an extra dot that won't delete in upper right corner). Fill doesn't work and I can't download new software onto the computer. I would be more than happy to send the file if you think you can fix it for me.
[image]

[image]

Comment: That dot in the top right corner is the origin of the object, not a vertex, every object has one.
Also when i read the title i thought you want to make a chain, while it looks more to me that you want to make a pendant for a key-chain and most likely want to 3D print it right? I would suggest to adjust the title, making it easier for others knowing this topic better, to find the question easier and thus giving you faster help. Also, to be able to help further, it may help if you share the .blend file.

Comment: Thank you Xylvier. Ok I was confused because the origin was originally centered until I tried adding a circle for the hole but it would't combine correctly so I deleted the circle but I guess the origin changed location when I combined them. I have changed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked if someone could fix it (well i tried):

[image]

I would like to roughly tell you what i did, so you could do it too, next time.
After converting the path to a mesh **(**"**Object-Menu**" -> "**Convert to**" -> "**Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text**"**)** and cleaning it reasonable, way to many points.
I separated the parts and made the main body from just the outer line extruded with a n-gon face. The rest was separating all the parts based on what layer they go. Like some framing of the text was cut out of the body and the text then set inside the cut out part giving it that depth.

If this is what you were trying to make is questionable, in the file is one pendant object that was the union of all parts, as well as a pendant in parts.
In case you want the faces that are cut in the body to be rather outside, just select all the vertices in the inner part of the body from the side-view and move them along the "Z" axis up. Would have liked to clean it up more, hope this helps you.

Btw. i was missing those bells, could not find them in the file.

[image]

Comment: Thank You! This has helped immensly!